# Resize the iframe in tumblr frame work

Tags: css, iframe, tumblr

hi i m going to edit like video section in tumblr theme i m facing problem when i resize the iframe using css its going outside from my box you can see:

- [Website](http://artisticsole.tumblr.com/)
- [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGuy5.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[FITVIDS.JS](http://fitvidsjs.com/)** will help you with your issue with non-resized video